# MERN app logout problem, cookie is not deleting

Tags: web, cookies, jwt, mern, react-fullstack

I am working on a MERN app. The app is working well on the localhost, both client and server. I deployed the app with some production environment changes like CORS, etc. I have solved many errors in this application, but this one error this not solvable.

The main problem, in production when I click the logout button it says successfully logged out, but the cookie in the browser was not deleted. in localhost, it is working well. The API endpoints of login and logout are given below. if anyone has a solution please answer my question.

---

below
login endpoint

```
router.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
    const { email, password } = req.body

    try {
        let user = await User.findOne({ email })
        if (!user) return res.sendStatus(404)

        const passwordMatch = bcrypt.compare(password, user.password)
        if (!passwordMatch) return res.sendStatus(401)

        const exp = Date.now() + 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30 // 30 days
        const token = jwt.sign({ email, exp }, process.env.SECRET)

        res.cookie("Authorization", token, {
            expires: new Date(exp),
            httpOnly: true,
            sameSite: "None",
            secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production",
        })

        res.sendStatus(200)
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
        res.status(400).json({ message: "user not found" })
    }
})
```

logout endpoint

```
router.get("/logout", (req, res) => {
    try {
        res.clearCookie("Authorization", {
            httpOnly: true,
            secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production",
            sameSite: "None",
        })
        res.sendStatus(200)
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err.message)
        res.sendStatus(400)
    }
})
```

---

**LIVE app : https://notes-app-frontend-pi.vercel.app**

**GITHUB REPOSITORY : https://github.com/Aayuslad/Notes-App**
If you want to see the whole code. the repo is there.

I want a solution for logout error. I know that the error is in the clierCookie function.

Comment: If saving a valid cookie works, you can try to set a cookie to a empty string to replace the valid one, and you get the logout behaviour (not a best-practices) but you'll get it done